# Calculation of Late Arrival / Early Arrival From In / Out Time

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time

I have table - attendance

```
staff_id |   in_date  |  out_date  | shift_in | shif_out | in_time  | out_time 
    1      2013-09-10   2013-09-10   06-30-00   15-00-00   07-00-00   15-00-00
    2      2013-09-10   2013-09-11   20-00-00   06-00-00   19-00-00   06-00-00
    3      2013-09-10   2013-09-11   23-00-00   06-00-00   23-30-00   07-00-00
```

I need to get result as

```
staff_id | late_time | early_time | extra_time 
    1      00-30-00    00-00-00     00-00-00
    2      00-00-00    01-00-00     00-00-00
    2      00-30-00    00-00-00     01-00-00
```

Can I achieve the result from mysql query itself or Do I need to use PHP to calculate this ? How can I get this result ?

Comment: You probably need MySQL's `TIMEDIFF` or `DATEDIFF`. Currently I can't see, how your columns are derived exactly.

Comment: The problem is staff id 2 and 3 , in date and out date is different. How can calculate this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I would use "DATETIME" in one Column instead of having a DATE column and a TIME column - this makes it easier to compare the Dates and get differences.

Then use "[TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)()" to compare the times to get the difference.

If your DB-Layout is already set, use [ADDTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) to combine the different columns into one DATETIME column like this:

```
SELECT TimeDiff(AddTime(in_date,shift_in), AddTime(out_date,in_time)) AS late_time
```